# Identifying height of a button using jquery gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having an issue getting the height of an object. Please excuse the mass (and mess!) of code it was easier to show the issue this way.

To recreate problem - hit the blue 'play' button - then click the green 'back to where we were' button.

You will see that it doesn't work on the return and I am completely stuck.

To make matters worse I am calculating the height on an element that is visibility: hidden - so I can't even tell if it is collapsing in some weird way!

The problem lies in the atrocity that is my 'getheight()' function but I can't see where it is causing the issue. (code here for reference - the fiddle tells the full story.)

**please help me out guys - and do'nt criticise my 'code as I think mess' too much :-D**

p.s. - as this is turning into a rather complex and messy lot of code and alternative ways to achieve what I am trying to achieve (morph one container to another without having to absolutely position either of the items) would be appreciated - just some ideas dont want code writing for me!

[Fiddle illustrating problem](http://jsfiddle.net/cd1Lpao7/)

```
function getHeight(elem){
var parent = $(elem).parent();
  if(parent.css('display') == "none"){
    console.log('parent');
    parent.css('display', 'hidden');
    parent.css('position', 'absolute');
    parent.css('display', 'block');

    theHeight = $( elem ).height();


    parent.css('display', 'none');

    return theHeight;

  }else{
    console.log('element');

    var beforePos = $(elem).css("position");
    var beforeDisplay = $(elem).css("display");
    var beforeVisibility = $(elem).css("visibility");

    $(elem).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(elem).css('position', 'absolute');
    $(elem).css("cssText", "display: block !important");

    console.log("DISPLAY" + $(elem).css('display'));
    theHeight = $(elem).height();
    console.log(theHeight);
    console.log(beforeVisibility);
    console.log(beforeDisplay);
    console.log(beforePos);
    console.log(elem);

    $(elem).css("cssText", "");

    $(elem).css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(elem).css('display', beforeDisplay);
    $(elem).css('position', beforePos);
    return theHeight;
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't get the size of an element that's not visible. Could you work around it by saving the dimensions to a data-attribute when the play button is first clicked, and then using those instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mark for pointing me to the documentation - the fix was actually quite simple once I knew what inconsistency jQuery has -

changed:-

```
theHeight = $(elem).height();
```

to

```
theHeight = $(elem).css("height");
```

and it functions as it should!

[now working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd1Lpao7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

as for getting height of hidden element, jQuery page says this:

The value reported by .height() is not guaranteed to be accurate when the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, ensure the element is visible before using .height(). jQuery will attempt to temporarily show and then re-hide an element in order to measure its dimensions, but this is unreliable and (even when accurate) can significantly impact page performance. This show-and-rehide measurement feature may be removed in a future version of jQuery.

[link to the jQuery height function](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: now that is a shame - I have a perfect working version that uses vanilla script and wraps the item in a parent div but was looking to avoid that - ah well back to the drawing board - thanks